# Curl ignores CURLOPT_FILE

Tags: php, curl

I want to download file with CURLOPT_FILE option.

```
$file_name = 'm1.dat';

$file = fopen($file_name, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($download_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($file);
```

I expect, that file would be saved in $file, but $file is empty, and curl_exec returns content of 
the file in $res. So, i must use file_put_contents($file_name, $res) to save the file.

But I want to download BIG files (1Gb and more), and, as I read, downloading whith CURLOPT_FILE is more memory efficient. With file_put_contents my script can run out of memory.

So, why curl not saving file to $file? I use PHP 7.3.9 and I have such problem both on Windows and Linux OS.

Comment: I tried it before I post my question, but I have same result - curl_exec($ch) returns content of the file in $res, and $file is empty.

Comment: If CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is false, curl_exec prints content of the file on console.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99082 suggests putting the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER before the CURLOPT_FILE

Comment: Yes! It works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the notes of curl_setopt (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#99082) it looks as though you should have the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` before the `CURLOPT_FILE` option...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
```